# Twoway databinding between dependency property of custom control and viewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have custom control

```
class SearchComboBox : ComboBox,  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChoosenItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ChoosenItem",
    typeof(ISearchable),
    typeof(SearchComboBox))

    public ISearchable ChoosenItem
    {
        get
        {
            return (ISearchable)GetValue(ChoosenItemProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(SearcherProperty, value);
        }
    }

      private void SearchComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
      {          
          var selected = this.SelectedItem as ISearchable;
          ChoosenItem = selected;
      }
}
```

In XAML I bind my custom property to ViewModel:

```
<controls:SearchComboBox ChoosenItem="{Binding SearchableAuthor, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="219"/>
```

And VM property to bind:

```
public ISearchable SearchableAuthor
    {
        get
        {
            return searchAuthor;
        }
        set
        {
            searchAuthor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchableAuthor");
        }
    }
```

When I modify `ChoosenItem` in user control `SearchableAuthor` of VM changes too, but when I try to change `SearchableAuthor`, `ChoosenItem` stays the same.
How to update this property from ViewModel?

Comment: Are you sure of `var selected` type? Also is this a typo mistake an additional parenthesis: `SetValue(ChoosenItemProperty, (ISearchable)`? What is `SetValue` btw?

Comment: @FirstStep Yes, I've tried to replace `ISearchable` with `string` type - same result.

Comment: So if you change `SearchableAuthor`, the setter for `ChoosenItem` never fires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filally I've got solution - add `ValueChanged` listener to dependency property:

```
 public TestBindingButton() : base()
    {
        this.Click += TestBindingButton_Click;
        var prop = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ChoosenItemProperty, typeof(TestBindingButton));
        prop.AddValueChanged(this, SourceChangedHandler);

    }
```

and manually access getter:

```
void SourceChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Content = ChoosenItem;
    }
```

Sample project to demonstrate what I've tried to achieve: [TwoWayBinding](https://bitbucket.org/ad_ray/twowaybinding/src)

Answer (score 0):

Add RelativeSource or ElementName to make it work.

```
<controls:SearchComboBox ChoosenItem="{Binding SearchableAuthor, 
   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
   Mode=TwoWay}" Width="219"/>

<controls:SearchComboBox ChoosenItem="{Binding SearchableAuthor, 
   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
   Mode=TwoWay}" Width="219"/>
```

You may also need to set the the DataContext of control to itself

```
public control()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```